# Filter JSON output with regex (or JSONSlurper?)

Tags: json, regex, groovy

Trying to achieve this by using the following script, which I want to extend with a loop to loop through the input. This should filter on the objects with have the value "valse", the others should be deleted/replaced.

```
def Message processData(Message message) {

    //getBody & new jsonSlurper
    def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String
    def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body)

    if (data.value != "false") {
        body = body.replaceAll(~/^(.*?)\childNodes/, "")
        message.setBody(body);
    } else {
    }
    return message
}
```

Input:

```
[{
    "name": "1",
    "value": "true",
    "childNodes": [{
        "name": "2",
        "value": "true",
        "childNodes": [{
            "name": "3",
            "value": "false",
            "childNodes": [{
                "name": "4",
                "value": "false"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{
        "name": "3",
        "value": "false",
        "childNodes": [{
            "name": "4",
            "value": "false"
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: In `desired output` you have item with `value=false` but in question you are saying that you want to keep only  `value=true`

Comment: The question is confusing. You left false values in your output. Also, is it possible to have multiple elements in the array? What is a true node has false children and vice versa?

Comment: @daggett You're right, edited.

Comment: @h8red No, no true child value after a false value

Comment: Is it correct to say that you need to find first child with value=false and return it with all children?

Comment: @daggett, yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only a single child object every time and that your task is finding the first `value=false` node and returning it with all the child nodes, you can do the following:

```
def processData(String message) {
    def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(message)[0]
    while (data.value != 'false') { data = data.childNodes[0] }
    return new JsonBuilder([data]).toPrettyString()
}
```

Here's a Spock test to go with it (replaced pretty string with regular json string so that it's easier to compare strings with ==)

```
class ParseSpec extends Specification {
    def testString = '''
    [{
        "name": "1",
        "value": "true",
        "childNodes": [{
            "name": "2",
            "value": "true",
            "childNodes": [{
                "name": "3",
                "value": "false",
                "childNodes": [{
                    "name": "4",
                    "value": "false"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
    '''

    def processData(String message) {
        def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(message)[0]
        while (data.value != 'false') { data = data.childNodes[0] }
        return JsonOutput.toJson([data])
    }

    def 'run test'() {
        expect:
        '''[{"name":"3","value":"false","childNodes":[{"name":"4","value":"false"}]}]''' == processData(testString)
    }
}
```

Comment: While isn't working in this case; java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'value' on null object. Which is strange, because if is working

Comment: In which case? I certainly tested it on the string you provided.

Comment: Anyways, i added the test you can use to check if its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
import groovy.json.*

def body ='''
[{
    "name": "1",
    "value": "true",
    "childNodes": [{
        "name": "2",
        "value": "true",
        "childNodes": [{
            "name": "3",
            "value": "false",
            "childNodes": [{
                "name": "4",
                "value": "false"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
'''

def filter(arr){
    for(i in arr){
        if(i.value == 'false') return [i]
        def filteredChild = filter(i.childNodes)
        if(filteredChild)return filteredChild
    }
    return null // not found
}

def filtered = filter( new JsonSlurper().parseText(body) )
println new JsonBuilder(filtered).toPrettyString()
```

Comment: This work in an online compiler, but it doesn't work in the tool I'm using. Groovy 2.4.1. Seems to struggle with def filter(arr). What does it actually do? Can't find this on google

Comment: it's declaration of function. in your original code you are also have function declaration `def Message processData(Message message) {...}` just declare `filter` function near by yours...